# Can't git push to Bitbucket.org -- with ssh keys

Tags: linux, ssh, git, rsync, bitbucket.org

I'm running doku-wiki on may (Ubuntu) laptop for some note taking.

So, to keep backup, I was using Bitbucket and periodically `pushed` my wiki files there and everything worked smoothly.

**(a)** Some time ago I set up `rsync` to backup a site on another machine to my laptop as well. I didn't want for the password vault on Ubuntu to ask me my passphrase for opening ssh to the server with the site, so I removed this password protection from my ssh keypairs (I can't remember how, but it was something strait forward in Linux).

To remove the passphrase from private key I entered the following command:
`ssh-keygen -p` as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112396/how-do-i-remove-the-passphrase-for-the-ssh-key-without-having-to-create-a-new-ke

Today I wanted to push my repository for notes to the Bitbucket but it gives weird errors.

My notes wiki belogs to www-data user and group.

When doing `git push origin master`, I get

```
b@s:/home/www-data/www/hi$ git push origin master
fatal: Unable to create '/home/www-data/www/hi/.git/refs/remotes/origin/master.lock': Permission denied
```

If I do `sudo git push origin master`, I get

```
b@s:/home/www-data/www/hi$ sudo git push origin master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

My suspicion was related to **(a)**, I thought maybe I changed my public key in some way, so I updated the public key again to Bitbucket.org. But the error persists.

The following is the output of `ssh -vT git@bitbucket.org`:

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [131.103.20.168] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/b/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/b/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/b/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/b/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/b/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/b/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/b/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/bismailov/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Remote: Forced command: conq username:b
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Remote: Forced command: conq username:b
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to bitbucket.org ([131.103.20.168]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_CA.UTF-8
logged in as b.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2752, received 2888 bytes, in 1.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 2808.2, received 2947.0
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Would be great if you can direct me in right path with this.

Comment: Try to remember what you did to remove the password protection. Doesn't `history` help you?

Comment: Use `ssh -vT git@bitbucket.org` to see what's happening with the authentication. Also make sure `git remote -v` that origin is set correctly.

Comment: I appended `ssh -vT git@bitbucket.org` output to my post.